# SQL 2005 get data from file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, file, import

I have data in a simple txt file, a trying to query it (to put it in a table) but when I use

```
select *
from OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',
       'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DefaultDir=C:\DB\;Extensions=TXT;',
       'select * from data.txt ');
```

I get the rows but all are NULL because (i think) there is no field terminator and is in UTF-16LE format, in the TXT all the fields are know by the character count, example:

```
FIELD1FIELD2FIELD3FIELD4FIELD5FIELD6
FIELD1FIELD2FIELD3FIELD4FIELD5FIELD6
FIELD1FIELD2FIELD3FIELD4FIELD5FIELD6
FIELD1FIELD2FIELD3FIELD4FIELD5FIELD6
```

To make things even worse, **the file is in UTF-16LE** but I need it in UTF-8 (or change the format within sql 2005) so that openrowset will work

And when I use

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ( BULK 'C:\DB\data.txt', SINGLE_NCLOB) AS BinFile
```

I get all the data but in a single row :(

Thanks in advance

ps: also used sp_addlinkedserver and didnt work

Comment: Hi, just curious, can you use an SSIS package to import the text file instead?

Comment: Nope, for that I need to install more things that cant be installed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your time and brains to try to crack up this problem, finally got it solved with:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(F1, 1, 19) col 1
    ,SUBSTRING(F1, 20, 19) col 2
FROM OpenRowset(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',   
     ''Text;HDR=NO;CharacterSet=unicode;Database='+@path+';
     Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1" '',JOURNEY_PLAN#txt);
```

**SUBSTRING** to get the data from a file that is not limited by nothing

**CharacterSet=unicode**  to enable the DB engine to read from a specific character set of the file

Thanks!!!!!!!!!

ps: In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177651.aspx found the details on the attribute "CharacterSet", the bad thing is that in the manual for OPENROWSET dosent says a thing about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx  >:(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `BULK INSERT` for this?

```
BULK INSERT dbo.myTable FROM 'C:\temp\MyFile.txt'
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

[MSDN Bulk Insert Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but there are some problems with this: the file dosent have field delimeter, the fields are set by char count so I have to do a substring after I upload the raw data, I run uir query with ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' but didnt work :( says: "Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file."

Comment: So you're working with a fixed width column file?  You would be able to use a format file.  If you want, I can include an example.

Comment: please do :D, also if u can, the file is in ascii and I need it in other thing like utf-8, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the contents of data.txt is [in the correct format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If it is not formatted correctly, then NULL values will be returned when it cannot be interpreted. For example, if the data file looks like this:

```
f1,f2,f3
1,x,3
a,b,c
```

Then the driver will interpret the first and third fields as some kind of numeric value and then will return NULL for fields `f1` and `f3` in the second row of data.

**Edit** For the given example data, make sure you have something like the following in your schema.ini file:

```
[data.txt]
Format=FixedLength
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=Field1 Text Width 6
Col2=Field2 Text Width 6
Col3=Field3 Text Width 6
Col4=Field4 Text Width 6
Col5=Field5 Text Width 6
Col6=Field6 Text Width 6
```

Comment: Hi mark, the fields are set by char count, not by a character, example  

Field1Field2Field3Field4
Field1Field2Field3Field4
Field1Field2Field3Field4
Field1Field2Field3Field4
Field1Field2Field3Field4
Field1Field2Field3Field4
Field1Field2Field3Field4
Field1Field2Field3Field4

Comment: chulian: Maybe add example data that results in the NULLs to the original question.  Someone may have more ideas if they see a sample.  (It is a bit difficult to read in the comment).

Comment: will add details to the question Mark ;)

Comment: Thanks mark!, sadly I cant modify the file to add format info, I had some progress when I change the encoding from UTF-16 to UTF-8 I can query the file (but the first row is the cols name...  ) and use substring to split the single row in multiple cols, but aside that im stuck in mud..... im really frustrated with sql 2005, a simple thing as this has become a living hell

Comment: @chulian:  Good luck in figuring it out.  Too bad it's turning into such a hassle.  It all worked fine for me with a UTF-8 file and setting the ColNameHeader=True flag in the schema.ini file.  But I didn't have any characters above 0x7f (all single-byte values).  A fixed width format definitely will not work if you have any characters that require more than one byte.

Comment: Thansk guys for ur support :D im working on a "workaround" using DTS hopes it does the trick :P